# ggplot2: How to get dots to group with violin plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I would like to plot violin plots where x axis is `exon` however I want to group the plots. This works if its just violins however when I add in the jitters for some reason its not responding the correct `aes` and is plotting on its own?  Here is a reproducible code with a screen shot of the error. thanks!

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  exons = c(rep("e1", 200), rep("e2", 200)),
  values = rnorm(400, 200, 40),
  group = c(
    rep("g1", 75), rep("g2", 75), rep("g3", 50),
    rep("g1", 75), rep("g2", 75), rep("g3", 50)
  )
)

ggplot(df, aes(y = values, x = exons, fill = group)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_jitter(shape = 16, position = position_jitter(0.07))
```

so if the plot works the dots should had been plotted within each of the group for each exon, however here it is clearly not.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want both `position_dodge()` and `position_jitterdodge()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y = values, x = exons, fill = group)) +
  geom_violin(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(seed = 1, dodge.width = 0.9))
```

[image]

Another option worth mentioning is `geom_quasirandom()` function from the [`ggbeeswarm`](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) package

```r
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(df, aes(y = values, x = exons, fill = group)) +
  geom_violin(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_quasirandom(dodge.width = 0.9, varwidth = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Suggestion: use raincloud plot instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630293/how-to-show-whiskers-and-points-on-violin-plots

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
set.seed ( 1)
df = data.frame ( 
  exons = c(rep("e1", 200), rep("e2", 200))
  ,values = rnorm(400,200,40)
  ,group = c(rep("g1", 75), rep("g2", 75), rep("g3",50),
             rep("g1", 75), rep("g2", 75), rep("g3",50) )
)

ggplot(df, aes(y= values  , x= exons , fill = group )) +
  geom_violin()+ 
  geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(width = NULL, height = NULL))
```

You can define the degree of jitter in x and y direction.

Comment: Thats clever however not exactly since its not grouping correctly.  I don't have a working example but pretty much the dots should jitter inside the violins. something like this. http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/figure/ggplot2/ggplot2-violin-plot-dot-plot-data-visualization-2.png