# jitter according to density

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want to create a combination of violin- and dot-plot with ggplot. The idea is to shift the dots to the left and right if necessary, to avoid overlap.

I know that geom_dotplot does this (left example), but it also groups the dots on the y axis, which I don't want (giving the impression that y is not continuous). geom_jitter also works, but that way it jitters the values independent of the corresponding density.

[image]
So my ideal plot would be the x position form geom_dotplot but with the true y position. Is there a way to achieve that with ggplot?

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(values=c(rnorm(100, mean = 0),rnorm(100, mean = 1)), typ= c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))

ggplot(data, aes(x=typ,y=values))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y",stackdir='center',binwidth = 0.1)

ggplot(data, aes(x=typ,y=values))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
```

thank in advance.

Comment: the ggbeeswarm package is your friend. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbeeswarm/vignettes/usageExamples.pdf

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57445054/7941188

Comment: `ggforce::geom_sina()` can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the {ggbeeswarm} package. I'd use `ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom` for this case.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

data <- data.frame(values=c(rnorm(100, mean = 0),rnorm(100, mean = 1)), typ= c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))

ggplot(data, aes(x=typ,y=values))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_quasirandom()
```

[image]

Or, as per Richard Telford's comment, ggforce::geom_sina does a similar job. I personally prefer geom_quasirandom because it seems to distribute the points slightly more regularly.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=typ,y=values))+
  geom_violin()+
  ggforce::geom_sina()
```

[image]