# Violin scatter plots with dependent variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, boxplot, violin-plot

Here is my dataset 'cellcounts':

`Treatment DAPI DAPO DAPU
1      DMSO   20   30   40
2      DMSO   24   26   42
3      DMSO   23   24   39
4 EPZ 0.5uM   10   25   22
5 EPZ 0.5uM   12   24   22
6 EPZ 0.5uM   14   24   30
7 EPZ 0.5uM   20   19   32`

I am trying to create a violin scatter plot with the Treatment groups on the x-axis and the cell counts (DAPI, DAPO, DAPU) on the y-axis, so in total I should have six violin plots.

```
p1<-ggplot(cellcounts,aes(x=Treatment,y=DAPI)) +geom_violin(aes(colour="DAPI"),alpha=0.5)+ geom_jitter(data=cellcounts,shape=16,position=position_jitter(0.2),colour="blue")+ geom_boxplot(width=0.1,fill="grey")
```

Obtains a Violin plot with box plot and scatter point [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA1PR.png)

I can add the Violin plots for the DAPO and DAPU data also [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6nej.png) with

```
p2<-p1+geom_violin(aes(Treatment,DAPO,colour="DAPO"),alpha=0.5)

p3<-p2+geom_violin(aes(Treatment,DAPU,colour="DAPU"),alpha=0.5)
```

If I try to add the jitter plot now with

```
p3+geom_jitter(data=cellcounts,shape=16,position=position_jitter(0.2),colour="blue")
```

it is only added for the DAPI data as this is what's used the the ggplot demand (?) how can I add the data points for the DAPO and DAPU data also?

I also want DAPI Violin and jitter points to be blue, DAPO green and DAPU red.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You might be interested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630293/how-to-show-whiskers-and-points-on-violin-plots

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, first you pivot the data into long format so you don't need to specify each column with a command:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

p = ggplot(pivot_longer(cellcounts,-Treatment),aes(Treatment,value))+
geom_violin(aes(col=name),position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) +
geom_point(aes(shape=name),col="blue",position=position_dodge(width=0.3))
```

print(p)

[image]

As you can see above, I plotted the violins "dodged", meaning not on the same vertical line, and for your data points to be aligned, normally we would use color to be the same. Since you wanted blue for all dots, I just use shape as a variable to allow them to align.

If you like them to be the same shape, just do:

```
p+scale_shape_manual(values=c(20,20,20))
```