# How do I colour jitter points to be different colours in a geom_boxjitter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, jitter

I'm trying to match the colours of the points from the jitter plot to the colours of the boxes. I can colour them one colour or the other, but I can't seem to set them to match the colour of the boxes.

Alternatively, I've figured out how to change the colours of the jitter points using geom_jitter but can't seem to figure out how to shift them to the side of the boxplot like the geom_boxjitter would have them. I thought maybe I could add "position = ..." to my geom_jitter() but that didn't seem to work...

Jitter box plot with dots in black
[image: Jitter box plot with dots in black]

Jitter box plot with correct colour dots, but overlapping with boxes
[image: JItter box plot with correct colour dots, but overlapping with boxes]

```
#hybrid jitter-box with jitter points all same colour
ggplot(all.bio2)+
  geom_boxjitter(aes(x=season, y=S.chao1, fill=season),
                                jitter.colour = ,
                                outlier.colour = NULL, outlier.shape = 1,
                                errorbar.draw = T, 
                                errorbar.length = 0.2)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))

#hybrid jitter-box with different coloured points but overlapping with boxes
ggplot(all.bio2)+
  geom_boxjitter(aes(x=season, y=S.chao1, fill=season),
                                jitter.colour = NA,
                                outlier.colour = NA, outlier.shape = 1,
                                errorbar.draw = T, 
                                errorbar.length = 0.2)+
  geom_jitter(aes(x=season, y=S.chao1, colour=season), width = 0.15)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question at first, I edited my code, it should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this post [How to plot a hybrid boxplot: half boxplot with jitter points on the other half?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003863/how-to-plot-a-hybrid-boxplot-half-boxplot-with-jitter-points-on-the-other-half), you have to use `jitter.color = NA` and `jitter.shape = 21` in order to have the same color between the boxplot and jitter points

So, for your code, you should try:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpol)

ggplot(all.bio2, aes(x = as.factor(season), y = S.chao1, fill= as.factor(season))) +
  geom_boxjitter(jitter.shape = 21, jitter.color = NA,
                 outlier.colour = NULL, outlier.shape = 1,
                 errorbar.draw = T,
                 errorbar.length = 0.2)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```

It works for me (using `mtcars` dataset)

**Example** (using `mtcars` dataset)

```r
library(ggpol)
library(ggplot2)
df = mtcars[c(1:20),]
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill= as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxjitter(jitter.shape = 21, jitter.color = NA,
                 outlier.colour = NULL, outlier.shape = 1,
                 errorbar.draw = T,
                 errorbar.length = 0.2)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```

[image]